# How to modify footer section of magento

Tags: theme, footer, magento-1.7.0.1

How to modify and edit this getChildHtml functions because i want to add different html into footer section.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_footer') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `path_to_theme/layout` and create a file called `local.xml` and have this code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <refernece name="footer">
       <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>path_to_theme/page/html/new_footer.phtml</template>
       </action>
  </reference>
</layout>
```

Now create file called `path_to_theme/page/html/new_footer.phtml` and have any html you want.

I would suggest you to look at `path_to_theme/page/html/footer.phtml` file to include some default attributes in your new file, so that you don't miss some important things.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin section System>Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Debug Then enable Template path hints. After this refresh your site frontend.

You will get the correct information from which theme your file is being loaded.

Then change the correct footer.phtml file.

For better knowledge read  [Themes hierarchy in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213665/magento-theme-hierarchy)

Comment: This suggests you change the footer.phtml inside of base which is not recommended practice.

Comment: @Smartie where it's suggest for base ??

Comment: There is no suggestion about copying the template in to your own theme if the template from path hints is found in base/default. That is all :)